# Difference between mathematical and Tensorflow implementation of Softmax Crossentropy with logit

Tags: logit, loss-functions, tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy

Softmax cross entropy with logits is define as follows:

$a_i = \frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_{\forall j} e^{z_j}}$

$l={\sum_{\forall i}}y_ilog(a_i)$

Where $l$ is the actual loss.

But when you look deep into [C++ Tensorflow implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bc86da090f2f2e850768bbdfd603c7217aecdb53/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/softmax_op.cc#L79) of `SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits` operation, the exact formula which they use is descibed as:

$l={\sum_{\forall j}}y_j ((z_j-max(z))-log({\sum_{\forall i}}e^{z_i-max(z)}))$

The part: $z-max(z)$ - is perfectly understood - it is just **normalization** which helps to avoid under/overflow.

**BUT:**

- Where is the actual `Softmax` in their implementation?
- Why from each $z_j$ they subtract $log({\sum_{\forall i}}e^{z_i-max(z)})$ before multiply it by $y_j$?

*Note: One may argue that the code I indicated is just Tensorflow's implementation of `CrossEntropyWithLogits` and not `SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits`.*

*But the actual [`SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bc86da090f2f2e850768bbdfd603c7217aecdb53/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/softmax_op.cc#L132) operation - additionaly checks only dimentions and do not perform any more computation.*

Answer (score 5):

Since Eigen's implementation the `log` function with base $e$, we know that $\log(e^{z_i}) = z_i$, and $\log({x \over y}) = \log x - \log y$, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\log(a_i) 
&= \log{e^{z_i - \max(z)}\over \sum_{\forall j}{e^{z_j - \max(z)} }} \\
&= \log({e^{z_i - \max(x)}) - \log({\sum_{\forall j}{e^{z_j - \max(z)}}}}) \\
&= (z_i - \max(z)) - \log({\sum_{\forall j}{e^{z_j - \max(z)}}})
\end{align}
$$

So
$$
\begin{align}
l & = -\sum_{\forall i} {y_i\log(a_i)} \\
 & = -\sum_{\forall i} {y_i} \log{e^{z_i - \max(z)}\over \sum_{\forall j}{e^{z_j - \max(z)} }}\\
 & = -\sum_{\forall i} {y_i} (z_i - \max(z)) - \log({\sum_{\forall j}{e^{z_j - \max(z)}}})
\end{align}
$$

To answer your questions:

- Where is the actual Softmax in their implementation?

Looking at my explanation above, you can see that the original formula of the Softmax has been transformed to $(z_i - \max(z)) - \log({\sum_{\forall j}{e^{z_j - \max(z)}}})$, and that is what tensorflow's implementation is. They are the same.

- Why from each $z_j$ they subtract $ \log(\sum_{\forall i}{e^{z_i−\max(z)}})  $ before multiply it by $y_j$?

This is the result of the transformation

**`Note:`**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy), the exact formula for the cross entropy should have a minus sign before the sum:
$$
l = -\sum_x{p(x)\log q(x)}
$$

Comment: Could you make it clearer where the first question in the OP's query is answered. It is best to be as explicit as possible about what exactly each part of the answer is addressing